# Using JMockit and TestNG with Spring framework

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, testng, jmockit

Spring framework has great integration with jUnit and EasyMock. Does anyone have experience using JMockit and TestNG with Spring framework?

Comment: Could you update your question with what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with TestNG with Spring framework. spring-test.jar library helps to integrate TestNG and JUnit by the way with Spring for testing purposes. If you use JMockit or not should not affect the way you use TestNG-SprintTest-Spring integration.